# jQuery is removed when reload

Tags: javascript, refresh

Im hiding a few elements with jquery. My website's filter is using ajax reloading and when its reloaded jquery is removed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sf-label-radio').text('');
    $('.sf-item-0').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: "jQuery is removed": what do you mean? Your effects disappear when you reload the page? If so, that's perfectly normal unless you store the state somewhere and reload it on page load.

Comment: Yes, my effects disappears. Sorry, how I can store them?

Comment: Actually depends on what you mean by "ajax reloading". You might just need to call your jQuery code again after said refresh. Please share a bit more code and context (by editing your question).

Comment: That might be not possible, because im using wordpress. And I'm doing some custom works with js and css. I just disabled the the ajax reloading, and its same now. I can share the url, but I'm not able to do this here.